# parent element affected by nth-child()

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
<style type="text/css">
 <!--    
    div:nth-child( 3n + 2 ) { background-color: green }
 -->
</style>

<div>
    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
    <div>three</div>
    <div>four</div>
    <div>five</div>
    <div>six</div>
    <div>seven</div>
    <div>eight</div>
    <div>nine</div>
    <div>ten</div>
    <div>eleven</div>
</div>
```

Why is the outer div affected by this style sheet rule even though it hasn't got a sibling and is the only child of a parent element?

Comment: Are there any other `div` elements on the page that this div would be a  child of? From the code you posted I can't recreate your error.

Comment: No other div elements only those posted.

Comment: But there is another style sheet : div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  border: thin;
  border-style: solid;
  margin: 20px; 
 }

Comment: Are you sure that `div` is the only child of its parent? Because your given code makes it appear like the `style` element is a sibling, yet neither element has a parent, and I'm not sure if that's intentional.

Comment: What DOCTYPE are you using, and exactly where is this `style` element? (Is it outside the `head`? Inside the `body`?) Can we see a whole, complete document, please?

Comment: The styles are in a seperate file.

Comment: The outer Div has got seven other sibblings that are not divs. Does that affect this rule? The outer div has got 5 <p> 1 <ul> and one <table> element.

Comment: Of course that affects the rule. `:nth-child()` is not [`:nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type).

Comment: @Volker Very much so. Please try to use complete, minimal examples that show the problem whenever you can.

Answer (score 6):

Because of the `<style>` element, the outer `<div>` **does** match the selector. [`:nth-child` is 1-indexed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child), so `nth-child(3n+2)` matches elements at indices 2 (n=0), 5 (n=1), 8 (n=2), ... and the presence of that `<style>` tag in your HTML means that the parent `<div>` is indeed at index 2 (remember, we start counting at 1).

See what happens when you move the `<style>` tag: http://cssdesk.com/PEBpL

You can solve this with a [more-specific selector](http://cssdesk.com/gSW2N), optionally with [more-specific HTML as well.](http://cssdesk.com/7Z7NC)

Comment: Is that link demonstrating what happens when the style element is removed (i.e. the expected results)?

Comment: Would this not suggest that adding an extra `<div>` in between the `<style>` and the existing parent `<div>` would make the problem go away? Because as far as I can tell, it doesn't.

Comment: Oddly, that seems to work when the style is in a separate CSS file, but not when the `style` element is in the body, as it looked like it might have been from the question (even with the `scoped` attribute in an HTML5 document.) Adding anything other than a `<div>` seems to work, though. And now I'm quite confused.

Comment: Aha! Ignore me, I've been confused by testing using `<div />` (invalid and treated as a opening tag) rather than `<div></div>`.

Answer (score 2):

As @MattBall said:

(Demonstration:)

http://jsfiddle.net/pbMM8/
With `style` element in the document.

http://jsfiddle.net/hd4xy/
With the separated css.

**UPDATE**
In case you don't want or can't separate the style,
consider adding an extra `div` to the css rule.

```
div div:nth-child( 3n + 2 ) { background-color: green }
```

As you can see at:
http://jsfiddle.net/J8SQJ/

Answer (score 1):

The problem does not occur in any valid HTML document. But if your document contains any non-whitespace content before the `<style>` tag, then things change. Such content implicitly closes the `head` element and starts the `body` element. The `style` element is then taken as the first child of `body` (which is invalid HTML, but works just fine as such in practice), making your `div` the second child and thereby matching the selector `div:nth-child( 3n + 2 )` (for `n` = 0).

A solution is to fix the HTML syntax so that `style` is in the `head` element. Use http://validator.w3.org to check the syntax.

In addition to this, it is safer to assign a class or an `id` attribute to the outer `div`, say `<div class=foo>`, and use a selector like `.foo > :nth-child(3n+2)`, which matches specific children of an element in a specific class.

Answer (score 0):

The outer div is the eighth sibbling in the document. Which means the nth-child( 3n + 2 )
applies correctly.

```
<body>

<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>

<ul></ul>

<table></table>

<div>
    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
    <div>three</div>
    <div>four</div>
    <div>five</div>
    <div>six</div>
    <div>seven</div>
    <div>eight</div>
    <div>nine</div>
    <div>ten</div>
    <div>eleven</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: This would have been obvious had you included the actual structure in the question to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. I really didn't think that far when I posted it. Great help. Cheers.